# Appium getClipboardText() is not working in Android newer version (i.e. >10)

Tags: appium

getClipboardText() is giving null value (only for Android-10 devices) even after setting some value to clipboard using setClipboardText(). Setting value is working fine both for android and ios & getting clipboard value is not working in newer version of Android. But it’s working fine in Android-9 versions.

Nothing is getting printed on console.

```
if (Constants.isAndroidTest) {
       sData = ((AndroidDriver<WebElement>) oDriver).getClipboardText();
} else {
       sData = ((IOSDriver<WebElement>) oDriver).getClipboardText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem before Nov 2019 but got fixed in newer versions. Try upgrading your appium version.
Problem Statement : Unless your app is the default input method editor (IME) or is the app that currently has focus, your app cannot access clipboard data on Android 10 or higher.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data